# Jquery get remove class on multiple elements exept last one

Tags: jquery

Alright I have multiple select boxes with the class "active_category"
I want to remove the class exept from the last input.

I get this:

```
<input type="text" class="active_category"/>
<input type="text" class="active_category"/>
<input type="text" class="active_category"/>
<input type="text" class="active_category"/>
```

And I want to change it to this:

```
<input type="text" class=""/>
<input type="text" class=""/>
<input type="text" class=""/>
<input type="text" class="active_category"/>
```

My current Jquery code for this is:

```
    var count = 1;
    var total = $(".active_category").length;
    $(".active_category").each(function () {
        if(count < total)
        {
            $(this).removeClass( "active_category" );
        }
        count++;
    });
```

Is there a shorter way of doing so??

Comment: use [not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) of jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for an `each`. Just use the `:not` and `:last` selectors:

```
$(".active_category:not(:last)").removeClass( "active_category" )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r52rwk77/1/

Comment: I would recommend you to wrap this code inside of this if block `if(count < total)` to match OP's requirement.

Comment: This is working, thank you. Will accept awnser when 10 minutes have passed.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu - I think that was just the OP's hack to try and get it to work.

Comment: The IF statement in my code was because of the count.
The solution sent by TrueBlueAussie gives me the exact result that I wanted.

Comment: @anothershrubery OMG, i just confused.. I thought it was some other logic in OP's point of view.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy: Feel free to remove comments... I will do the same (saves on noise) :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add context to my answer:

```
var count = 1;
var total = $(".active_category").length;
$(".active_category").each(function () {
    if(count < total)
    {
```

Then my answer:

```
        $(this).not(':last-child').removeClass( "active_category" );
```

Then the rest of your if statement:

```
    }
    count++;
});
```

To prove it works in a standalone version - http://jsfiddle.net/Lmt5ovd2/

**Note to down voter** - Lets think before we press that little button shall we?

Comment: How can you apply filter over a single element.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy He probably consider this line in the `.each()`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Oh.. I see.

Comment: The question was to shorten the code, my own worked fine aswell. But my request was to shorten it.

Comment: @user2022768, fair play, i missed that bit. Note to self, read all the question.

Comment: Doesnt needs to be included. That was just my way I used to have, and dont get me wrong, I didnt down-vote you as your solution was working after I looked correctly.

Comment: in that case @TrueBlueAussie is absolutely the right method.